# Mousedown no Chrome 55

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, eventos-do-mouse, javascript-eventos

Utilizo o evento `mousedown` em JS para atribuir uma ação ao meu objeto em um projeto em questão.

Com a nova atualização do google Chrome para a versão 55 meu evento não funciona mais!

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como utilizar o evento nesta nova release?

Atualmente utilizo a seguinte forma.

```
var iddiv = document.getElementById('meuid');

iddiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
});
```

Obrigado a todos!

```
iddiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    divSelc = e.target.id;
$("#"+divSelc).css("outline","3px solid red");
});
```

Comment: Tenho o Chrome `Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)` e funciona para mim... Podes testar aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/4zkahL3h/ e vê se funciona?

Comment: Coloca o código do seu elemento também.

Comment: Por curiosidade, a API [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerdown) é compatível com Chrome 55. Clonei o exemplo do @Sergio, com `pointerdown`, funcionou também: https://jsfiddle.net/0ur1webv/

Comment: @LucasCosta essa API vai simplificar a vida a muita gente quando os browsers adoptarem... boa sugestão.

Comment: Vai sim @Sergio, vai facilitar a captura dos diversos tipos de contatos com a tela em diferentes dispositivos, como essas canetas touch por exemplo

Comment: Vinicius:vi agora o teu edit... testa https://jsfiddle.net/4zkahL3h/1/ isto não funciona para ti?